# How can I display the ping of a server using jenkins?

Tags: c#, jenkins, oraclelinux

I have this application on visual basic being monitored by jenkins and running on an oracle server. Is there a way to show this server ping through jenkins? if not, any other tips?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using [Site Monitor Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/SiteMonitor+Plugin)
OR you could have a simple shell script running which pings your server and have it invoked by your Jenkins instance.

Comment: can you make a step-by-step of the second option? I'm new to all this Jenkins stuff.

Comment: first option don't work for me since he asks for a url and my server is not running in my machine.

Comment: @hari-haran is correct. I would have a job that runs a script that pings your server and sends you an email if it ever goes down.  We don't use Jenkins to alert us if a url goes down; we use newrelic, but that only works if your server is public, and not behind a firewall. A simple bash script or a python script to hit the url is the way to go.